# How to encrypt user passwords without symfony security

Tags: php, symfony, controller, sha256

I am using Symfony 4.0. I want to encrypt my user passwords with sha256 when they are registered. I don't want to use Symfony security but if there is no other way I will use it.

I tried with md5 and worked but with sha256 throws me an 
[exception](https://ibb.co/ypSNgMB).

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant sha256 - assumed 'sha256' (this will 
throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

That's my controller.

```
 public function register(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $user = $form->getData();
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //$user->setPassword(hash(sha256,$user->getPassword()));
        $user->setPassword(md5($user->getPassword()));
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
        $flashbag = $this->get('session')->getFlashBag();
        $flashbag->add("SuccessfullRegister", "You successfully registered in our site!");
        return $this->redirectToRoute('EventsAndPeople');
    }
    return $this->render('home/RegisterForm.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

For some reason, md5 works but sha256 doesn't.

Comment: "but with sha256 throws me an exception" - where is the exception? Please edit your question to add the Message of the exception.

Comment: I added the text of the exception and a screenshot of it as a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sha256** is not a constant, you have to supply this as a string. Change this line:

```
$user->setPassword(hash(sha256, $user->getPassword()));
```

to

```
$user->setPassword(hash("sha256", $user->getPassword()));
```

Note that i added quotation marks aroud `sha256`.